# What is the difference between port binding on an already open port and a closed port in Docker?

Tags: docker, networking, port

Start a busybox container as follows:

```sh
docker container run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 busybox
```

and on the host machine try listening on port `5000` (try netcat if you do not have nc):

```sh
nc -l -p 5000
Error: Couldn't setup listening socket (err=-3)
```

Now change the sequence, as in first start listening on the host:

```sh
nc -l -p 5000
```

and then start your container:

```
docker container run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 busybox
```

How come host still listening on port `5000` and container was able to start? How come host did not allow listening on port `5000` in the first situation?

I can even connect to the host machine from the container with hosts local IP (192.168.0.10 in my case):

```sh
/ # telnet 192.168.0.10 5000
Connected to 192.168.0.10
```

Why can I not first start the container with port binding but start listening later?

Comment: There's no process in the busybox container that is binding to the port. You're just forwarding connections, not opening anything

Comment: @cricket_007 Why does the host refuse to listen on `5000` in the first case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm just stating that you could try using a different container that does bind to a port if you're expecting both ways to fail

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not want both to fail, I kind of try to make the first situation work as well. I want to be able to listen on a port on host after a container was started with port bindings.

Comment: It's weird ;-) The only way this should work would be if docker and netcat were using different interfaces (each having a `:5000`) but that appears to not be the case because your first example would not then fail. If I try to repro this, I correctly (!) am able to use netcat to grab the port first but then docker fails `bind: address already in use`. And, if I reverse the commands, then netcat fails: `nc: Address already in use`. So, I can't explain the behavior you observe. It should work as you suspect. It does for me.

Comment: @DazWilkin Very interesting, I am using Mac, are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: This is on Linux

Comment: I suspect that's the reason. The Mac presumably runs Docker under virtualization. There's some incongruity in how this is effected.